# Is it possible to use a variable by providing its name through reflection?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get access to some string resources generated in R.java class at runtime.

R.java :

```
  public static final class string {
   public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    public static final int eightOvereight=0x7f040030;
    public static final int eightOvernine=0x7f040031;
    public static final int fiveOvereight=0x7f040027;
    public static final int fiveOverfive=0x7f040024;
    public static final int fiveOvernine=0x7f040028;
    public static final int fiveOverseven=0x7f040026;
    public static final int fiveOversix=0x7f040025;
    public static final int fourOvereight=0x7f040022;
    public static final int fourOverfive=0x7f04001f;
    {
```

At runtime I have:

```
     String current = getStringId(); // assume current = "eightOvereight" after this line

     //now I would like to use R.string.eightOvereight. I don't want to use a switch statement.
```

Can I achieve this through reflection?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: [Class::getField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String) is what you're looking for.

Comment: "Yes". Step #1 would be to *search* for this task. -1 because you *know* the mechanism and yet bring nothing: `android access variable reflection` seems like a pretty straight-forward search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Reflection, but... don't use Reflection. It should only be used in very, VERY rare cases. And this is not one of them.

Android provides a mechanism to pick variable resources at runtime.

```
String current = getStringId();

Resources res = context.getResources(); // Must provide an Activity or Context object here
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(current, "string", context.getPackageName());
// Do whatever with resourceId
```

You may want to look up [the documentation on `getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually a good idea to use reflection if the app does not really require it. You can get different resources at runtime by [using resource files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) depending on the conditions (screen size, API version, Locale etc) by defining resources in different folders with appropriate names.

Try to avoid reflection if possible. Also you assign `getStringId()` value which is supposed to be `int` to String variable.

```
String current = getStringId();
```

Comment: This is good advice, but it seems like more of a comment than an answer; it doesn't actually answer the OP's question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  But it is messy, complicated, inefficient and potentially fragile to use reflection for this.

It is better to do the lookup using a `HashMap`; e.g. assuming that you need those variables to exist as statics, then add this:

```
  private static Map<String, Integer> MAP = new Map<String, Integer> {{
      put("eightOvereight", eightOvereight);
      put("eightOvernine", eightOvernine);
      ....
  }
```

then fetch the values using `MAP.get(str)`.

---

Note - that is a general Java solution.  @Eric's answer provides a better Android-specific solution,.

Comment: Except Android will regenerate those static IDs in another build if the resources are modified...

Comment: actually those id's can change (your map values) so it's even more than fragile approach.